# Best way to io.emit in express controller

Tags: express, socket.io

Is the below a good pratice? Any other better way to do it?

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var data = { product: 'test', price: '90.00' };
    res.json(data);
    io.emit('value', data);
});
```

If res.render() is use, it won't work and need timeout to emit data.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `io.emit(...)` will send a socket.io message to all clients that are currently connected to this server.  If that's what you're trying to do, then `io.emit(...)` is the right way to do that.  `res.render()` and `res.json()` are for doing something entirely different.  The fact that you even mention `res.render()` and `io.emit()` as alternatives makes me wonder what you're trying to do (because they do very different things).

Comment: I just want to send message to all clients, but without res.json or res.render, the page will forever loop...

Comment: You have to return some response from the http request or the browser will still be waiting for a response.  You can just do `res.end()` to finish the response without sending any data.